# How to change the account association for external users?

Tags: sharepoint-online, external-users

A site was shared with an external user, bob@company.com. But, when they clicked the link to accept the invitation they were at home logged into their personal account, bobathome@outlook.com. Of course, this means that this personal Microsoft account will show up in the system for who modified files, etc. They would rather use their corporate office 365 account, bob@company.com.

What is the process for changing this association? Perhaps I need to fully delete the user account from Azure AD and start over? Anyone have a specific process for this?

This issue is raised in the [uservoice forums](https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/273493-office-365-admin/suggestions/7846581-properly-delete-an-external-users-from-o365), but I'm hoping the given answer from 5 years ago isn't current.

Answer (score 0):

You could go to user profiles in SharePoint Admin Center, find the profile of the external user in managed user profiles page. Then change the email adress, it should be work email property.